# Continuity of adjoint of algebra homomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras, continuous-homomorphisms

Consider unital (complex) abelian Banach algebras $A$ and $B$ with corresponding ideal spaces $\Sigma_A$ and $\Sigma_B$. Suppose $\rho:A\to B$ is a continuous algebra homomorphism that maps $1_A$ to $1_B$ and posseses an adjoint $\rho^*:B^*\to A^*$.

It is easy to see that for $h_B\in\Sigma_B$, $\rho^*(h_B)\in\Sigma_A$.

How would be the cleanest way of arguing that $\rho^*|_{\Sigma_B}:\Sigma_B\to\Sigma_A$ is indeed continuous?

**My current thoughts:** I need to show that $\Sigma_B\ni h_B\mapsto\rho^*(h_B)\in\Sigma_A$ is continuous, which is by definition (of adjoint equivalent) of $h_B\mapsto h_B\circ\rho$ being continuous. This sort of reminds me of the Gelfand transform. Is this the way to go? Is it as simple as arguing that both $h_B\mapsto h_B(b)$ and $\rho$ are continuous?

Comment: Some questions to possibly set you on the correct path:  What topologies are you placing on $\Sigma_A$ and $\Sigma_B$? Can you show continuity of $\rho^*$ without restricting to $\Sigma_B$?

Comment: @Aweygan $\Sigma_A$ and $\Sigma_B$ are (as I understand) supposed to carry the their respective weak$^*$ topologies (inherited from $A^*$ and $B^*$).

Comment: Thinking of it now, I'd assume I simply have to argue continuity of $\rho^*$ and use $\rho^*[\Sigma_B]\subseteq\Sigma_A$.

Comment: Yes and yes.  I'll post the rest of my advice as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly clean way to do this would be an argument involving nets.  Let $(h_i)_{i\in I}$ be a net in $\Sigma_B$ that converges to $h$ in the relative weak$^*$-topology. For any $x\in A$ we have
\begin{align*}
\rho^*(h)x=h(\rho(x))=\lim_{i\in I}h_i(\rho(x))=\lim_{i\in I}\rho^*(h_i)x.
\end{align*}
Thus $(\rho^*(h_i))_{i\in I}$ is weak$^*$-convergent to $\rho^*(h)$, which establishes continuity.